# Get objects name from inside extract

Tags: r, extract

I would like to write a function `gnl()` (getNamesLike), that when evaluated inside extract can retrieve the name of the object the `extract` is performed on. 
Is that **possible**?

Here is some code of the desired behavior:

```
gnl <- function(pattern) {grepl(pattern,names(mtcars))}
mtcars[,gnl("a")] %>% head
#                   drat am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         3.90  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     3.90  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        3.85  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    3.08  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 3.15  0    3    2
# Valiant           2.76  0    3    1

gnl <- function(pattern) {grepl(pattern,names(cars))}
cars[,gnl("i"),drop=F]  %>% head
#   dist
# 1    2
# 2   10
# 3    4
# 4   22
# 5   16
# 6   10
```

Of course `gnl()` needs to get the names (mtcars, cars, etc...) dynamically.

The farest I get is:

```
gnl <- function(data,pattern) {
    dplyr::select(data,dplyr::matches(pattern))
    }
mtcars %>% gnl("a")
```

Comment: Easier option is to have another data argument in the function or use `select` from `dplyr`

Comment: as per akrun comment, something like `gnl <- function(dat, patt) dat[, grepl(patt, names(dat)), drop=FALSE]`?

Comment: valid comment! `mtcars %>% select(matches("a"))` but I would love to have the above function if possible.

Comment: @RonakShah thanks for joining in. We had that workaround but that's not "neat" enough.

Comment: @AndreElrico Umm...then how do you want your `gnl` function to be? What input do you expect to be passed and what output do you want to get?

Comment: @RonakShah as put in my question. Input: only pattern, output: subset of matching column names. Somehow `gnl` need to access the name of the object in front of `extract`.

Comment: Just saw that workaround was already suggested earlier in comments. I am not sure, how can you get the object name without explicitly passing it.

Comment: I'm using this in my work for interactive use, as I often have very wide tables with prefixed or suffixed colnames : `'%like2%' <- function(df,pattern) {df[grepl(pattern,names(df))]}; mtcars %like2% "a"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work but is a bit of a hack..

```
dig_call <- function(call, call0_chr) {

  new_call <- call[[which(grepl(call0_chr, call, fixed = TRUE))]]

  if (identical(deparse(new_call), call0_chr)) {
    call[[2]]
  } else {
    dig_call(new_call, call0_chr)
  }
}

gnl <- function(pattern) {

  call0_chr <- deparse(sys.call(i <- 0))

  repeat {
    i <- i + 1
    call <- sys.call(i)
    find_call <- grepl(call0_chr, call, fixed = TRUE)
    if (any(find_call)) break
  }

  grepl(pattern, names(eval(dig_call(call, call0_chr), parent.frame())))
}
```

Principle:

1. You check the call stack iteratively until you get one call with `gnl`
2. This call may be composed of many calls (like the one with `%>% head()` for example) so that you need to dig into these calls recursively to get only the one with `gnl`
3. the second element of this call gives you the name of the object you're trying to subset (e.g. look at `as.list(substitute(mtcars[1]))`)
4. you do the filter on this object

Verification:

```
library(dplyr)
cars[gnl("i")]
cars[gnl("i")] %>% head()
cars[gnl("i")] %>% head() %>% head()
mtcars[gnl("i")]
mtcars[gnl("i")] %>% head()
```

Comment: this works even like this: `cars %>% {.[gnl("i")]} %>% head %>% head`

Answer (score 1):

With an extra S3 class:

```
`[.gnlable` <- function(x, i, j, drop = FALSE) {
  if (!missing(j)) {
    j <- substitute(j)
    j <- if (identical(j[[1]], quote(gnl))) grepl(j[[2]], names(x)) else eval(j)
  }
  `[.data.frame`(x, i, j, drop = drop)
}

class(cars) <- c("gnlable", class(cars))

cars[1:6, gnl("i"), drop = FALSE]
#   dist
# 1    2
# 2   10
# 3    4
# 4   22
# 5   16
# 6   10
```

Comment: it's cool but rather impractical to use. Since we have to add a class to it. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I get `Error in j[[1]] : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable`

Comment: @F.Privé I cannot reproduce with R 3.4.4 or 3.5 on Windows. Which version do you run on which OS? Maybe try with `as.list(j)[[1]]` and `as.list(j)[[2]]`